# Close a (dialog box) iFrame from a button within the iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two files, named `main_page.html` and `dialog_box.html` (see code below).
I  want my `handleCloseDialogButton()` to "close the dialog box", in other words to reload `main_page.html`,  with `theFrame.style.display` reset to "none".
  How can I do this ? Should I use `window.open("main_page.html")` or `window.location.href="main_page.html"` or something else ?
 Note: I do not want to use Javascript’s `alert()` function because its capabilities are not sufficient for what I need.

Contents of main_page.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<head>
<script>
function handleDialogButton()
{
var theFrame=document.getElementById("myDialogBox");
theFrame.style.display="block";
theFrame;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myDiv"> <h2> Hello world. This is the main page.</h2></div>
<iframe  id="myDialogBox" src="./dialog_box.html" style="display:none"> </iframe>
<input type="button" id="dbbutton" name="dbbutton" value="Open Dialog Box" 
onClick="javascript:handleDialogButton();" /> 
</body>
</html>
```

Contents of dialog_box.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<head>
<script>
function handleCloseDialogButton()
{

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myDiv"> <h2> Hello world. I am the dialog box.</h2></div>
<input type="button" id="cbbutton" name="cbbutton" value="Close Dialog Box" 
onClick="javascript:handleCloseDialogButton();" /> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `window.location.href="main_page.html"` will suffice. You could also reset the div: `document.getElementById("myDialogBox").style.display="none"`

Comment: @devqon your suggestion does not work. It merely displays the main page content inside the dialog box

Comment: I see, didnt read your question right. You mean close the iFrame from a button within the iFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access parent elements from iframe by using window.parent.
See [window.parent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.parent) for details.

With window.parent you can either call parent js function or you can access parent element. Accessing parent element in your case should look like: window.parent.document.getElementById('myDialogBox');

Use this in your handleCloseDialogButton function and set its display to none:

```
function handleCloseDialogButton()
{
window.parent.document.getElementById('myDialogBox').style.display="none";
}
```

**NOTE:** This will not work in file mode in Chrome. You have to put your pages on web server, and than it will work in Chrome browser too.